# Elementary questions on the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem

Tags: ct.category-theory

I have a few elementary questions about the Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem which I can't see  answered elsewhere here and which all arise from some confusions I ran into.

1. Can someone point out why (and where in the proof) exactly you need that the abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ is *small*?  Is it to show that the functor category $\mathsf{Fun}(\mathcal{A},\mathsf{Ab})$ is Grothendieck?
2. Does the FH embedding theorem also hold if $\mathcal{A}$ is only *essentially* small? I would say so but have seen this nowhere written out. If $\mathcal{A}$ is essentially small, there is an equivalence $F \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}'$ into a small category $\mathcal{A}'$. The category $\mathcal{A}'$ is automatically abelian and $F$ is an exact equivalence. Composed with the FH embedding of $\mathcal{A}'$ we get an exact embedding of $\mathcal{A}$ into a module category. Where's the mistake?
3. This one really confuses me. I thought that an exact embedding $F \colon \mathcal{A} \to R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ induces an isomorphism $\mathrm{Sub}(X) \to \mathrm{Sub}(F(X))$ between the lattices of subobjects of $X$ and $F(X)$, therefore maps simple objects to simple modules etc., and I can deduce the Jordan–Hölder theorem for a finite length object in $\mathcal{A}$ simply from the one for modules. But the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343130/applications-of-jordan-holder-theorem-in-an-abelian-category) here seem to indicate that this is wrong. Why is it so? I must be stupid here.

Answer (score 11):

1. You need this to know that $Fun(A,Ab)$ is locally small; and also indeed to check that $Fun(A,Ab)$ has nice properties such as Grothendieck-ness, or the existence of injective cogenerators etc. In other words it's needed for most of the steps that lead to the reduction to the case of a small subcategory of a nice Grothendieck abelian category.
2. Yes of course it works, and your argument shows that. I guess it's never written out because category theorists don't really care about the difference between small and essentially small. I would be surprised though if it were actually never mentioned.
3. It doesn't induce an isomorphism, only an embedding: given a subobject $Y\to F(X)$, how do you cook up a $Z$ such that $F(Z) \cong Y$ ? For instance look at the exact embedding $\mathbb Q-Mod\to \mathbb Z-Mod$, it certainly does not map simples to simples.

Comment: Re: 1, what happens in the proof of Freyd-Mitchell if you replace $[A, \text{Ab}]$ with the small presheaves on $A^{op}$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : I guess it depends on what you mean by small presheaves. $A$ might be big but not accessible, so maybe those don't behave appropriately. But it's a good question ! Certainly there'll still be issues with Grothendieck-ness since Grothendieck categories must be presentable, but small presheaves need not be as far as I can tell

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : one big thing for which smallness is used is the creation of an injective cogenerator/projective generator, and this uses a direct sum indexed by $A$ or something of a similar size, so one would have to find a way to bypass that

Comment: By small I just mean a small colimit of representables. And yes, that makes sense, I guess I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't an injective cogenerator.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : yeah I guess if you really really want to make everything work without the smallness assumption, the point where you will really be stuck is the point where you need a co/generator, the rest can probably be worked around by taking small presheaves and similar techniques

Comment: Fantastic! That answers all my questions. I'm baffled I fell over 3. For some reason I can neither upvote nor accept your answer. Could a moderator please do this for me?

Answer (score 10):

Here is an explicit counterexample when $A$ is not assumed to be small. Any abelian category admitting an exact (fully faithful) embedding into $\text{Mod}(R)$ must be [well-powered](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-powered+category), meaning every object must have a set of subobjects (since the same is true in $\text{Mod}(R)$ and an exact embedding induces an embedding on posets of subobjects, but not, as Maxime points out, an isomorphism). There are abelian categories that are not well-powered; you can see some examples in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93853/abelian-category-which-is-not-well-powered). I particularly like Jeremy Rickard's example of the (still locally small!) category of eventually constant functors $\text{Ord} \to \text{Ab}$.

Comment: Yes, exactly that came to my mind as well and I liked Rickard's example because it's down to earth in a sense.

Comment: Is there an example of a locally small well-powered abelian category that does not admit an exact embedding into a module category?